# Why do I see different results while editing my answer and after I post it?

Tags: support, answers, edits

Here is the link [How can I create an image with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711894/how-can-i-create-an-image-with-java/2711927#2711927)

I just cannot make a link look like a link but when editing it looks as it should be (try to edit https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2711927/edit).

Answer (score 3):

Your URL has spaces in it which have to be encoded.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: Yes, I missed that. But why was it correctly displayed while editing then?

Comment: @Roman, because the javascript (preview) parser and the C# (final view) parser are slightly different.